# How to get media card reader in NV52 Gateway to work?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, troubleshooting, storage, card-reader

Does anyone know how to get a built-in media card reader to work in Ubuntu 10.10? My laptop is a Gateway NV52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should "just work" and automatically mount when you insert a card.

If it's not, try this.  Insert a card with something on it.  Take a look at System > Administration > Disk Utility and see if the device appears as one of your storage devices.  If you can see it in the disk utility, look at its partitions and make sure the format is something we can read (ext, ntfs, fat or others).

Comment: As *dgmdan* said, this should work automatically when you insert a card. If it doesn't you should report a bug by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `ubuntu-bug`.

Comment: Maybe it's just my laptop or something. I've found out that it works sometimes. Other times I have to have the card in the reader when the OS loads for it to work. Otherwise, it wouldn't show up in Disk Utility